# Avoid namenode format to preserve data

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, hypertable

I have only one machine running namenode, and datanode. 
The machine got rebooted. Now the namenode is not coming up due to improper shutdown. 
the log says that namenode is not formatted. How do I bring it back? I have a lot of data stored in it and I cant afford to lose it.

```
2013-06-07 16:58:50,207 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = Server/10.15.21.21
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.2-cdh3u6
STARTUP_MSG:   build = file:///data/1/tmp/nightly_2013-03-20_11-32-44_3/hadoop-0.20-0.20.2+923.479-1~lucid -r efb405d2aa54039bdf39e0733cd0bb9423a1eb0a; compiled by 'root' on Wed Mar 20 13:10:08 PDT 2013
************************************************************/
2013-06-07 16:58:50,559 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=NameNode, sessionId=null
2013-06-07 16:58:50,563 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.metrics.NameNodeMetrics: Initializing NameNodeMeterics using context object:org.apache.hadoop.metrics.spi.NullContext
2013-06-07 16:58:50,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2013-06-07 16:58:50,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 17.77875 MB
2013-06-07 16:58:50,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2013-06-07 16:58:50,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
2013-06-07 16:58:50,671 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hdfs (auth:SIMPLE)
2013-06-07 16:58:50,672 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2013-06-07 16:58:50,672 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2013-06-07 16:58:50,705 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
2013-06-07 16:58:50,705 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2013-06-07 16:58:50,729 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.metrics.FSNamesystemMetrics: Initializing FSNamesystemMetrics using context object:org.apache.hadoop.metrics.spi.NullContext
2013-06-07 16:58:50,805 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:307)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:568)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1453)
2013-06-07 16:58:50,807 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:307)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:568)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1453)

2013-06-07 16:58:50,808 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at Server/10.15.21.21
************************************************************/
```

Comment: Where is your hdfs data directory? i.e What is the value in your config for `dfs.name.dir`? If it was `/tmp`, it was probably erased by the OS on reboot.

Comment: @highlycaffeinated - Yes, that is exactly what it was. I didn't add dir name in the config. I realized that soon after posting a question, no way I can get namenode data back since reboot deleted everything.